# How to check if program is running on .net 4.6.1

Tags: .net

How can I check if a program that is running on my PC is using .NET Framework 4.6.1?

I can see in the registry that it is installed, but how can I make sure that a specific program is using it?

Comment: you can use [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to look into the .net version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15128605/1271037

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to *not* use it, the 4.6.1 installer *replaces* any existing .NET 4.x install.  Only other framework version the program could be using is an old one, before .NET 4.0.  Do keep in mind that the framework version you target is not the same as the one you run with.

Otherwise easy to check with, say, SysInternals' Process Explorer or a debugger.  Look at the loaded DLLs.  A 4.x process always loads `clr.dll`, older framework versions did not yet have that DLL, they'd use mscorwks.dll instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Environment.Version()` (its worked for me on .NET 3.5) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version(v=vs.110).aspx